# Husky pre-commit not running in Windows

Tags: git, husky

I have set anything possible up, followed most guides & documentations,
but yet - the pre-commit hook does not run.

What I did:

1. `npx husky install`
2. created a file called: ".huskyrc.json"
3. Wrote to file:

   {
   "hooks": {
   "pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run test:no-watch && npm run format && git add ."
   }
   }

By the way, output of: `git config --get core.hooksPath` is `.husky`

Please advice? I do `git commit -m "test"` and nothing happends. It commits it without the hook being run